# Specifying different speeds for different vehicles when using ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, vehicle-routing-problem

I am using ArcGIS REST API Vehicle Routing Problem service. I have several different types of vehicles, such as cars and trucks. There is an optional parameter called "impedance" to specify the travel times for vehicles. But it is very general, and it cannot specify for each vehicle.

What should I do if I would like different vehicles with different speed factors?

For example, cars with 1.5 while trucks with 1.